# How to use a Objective-C #define from Swift

Tags: objective-c, macros, swift

I am migrating a `UIViewController` class to train a bit with Swift. I am successfully using Objective-C code via the bridging header but I have the need of importing a constants file that contains `#define` directives.

I have seen in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/BuildingCocoaApps.pdf) (Simple macros) the following:

> **Simple Macros**
>
> Where you typically used the `#define` directive to define a primitive constant in C and Objective-C, in Swift you use a global constant instead. For example, the constant definition `#define FADE_ANIMATION_DURATION 0.35` can be better expressed in Swift with `let FADE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.35`. Because simple constant-like macros map directly to Swift global variables, the compiler automatically imports simple macros defined in C and Objective-C source files.

So, it seems it's possible. I have imported the file containing my constants into the bridging header, but I have no visibility from my `.swift` file, cannot be resolved.

What should I do to make my constants visible to Swift?

**UPDATE:**

It seems working with `NSString` constants, but not with booleans:

```
#define kSTRING_CONSTANT @"a_string_constant" // resolved from swift
#define kBOOL_CONSTANT YES // unresolved from swift
```

Comment: Try using true instead of YES.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

At the moment, some `#define`s are converted and some aren't. More specifically:

```
#define A 1
```

...becomes:

```
var A: CInt { get }
```

Or:

```
#define B @"b"
```

...becomes:

```
var B: String { get }
```

Unfortunately, `YES` and `NO` aren't recognized and converted on the fly by the Swift compiler.

I suggest you convert your `#define`s to actual constants, which is better than `#define`s anyway.

.h:

```
extern NSString* const kSTRING_CONSTANT;
extern const BOOL kBOOL_CONSTANT;
```

.m

```
NSString* const kSTRING_CONSTANT = @"a_string_constant";
const BOOL kBOOL_CONSTANT = YES;
```

And then Swift will see:

```
var kSTRING_CONSTANT: NSString!
var kBOOL_CONSTANT: ObjCBool
```

Another option would be to change your `BOOL` defines to

```
#define kBOOL_CONSTANT 1
```

Faster. But not as good as actual constants.

Comment: May I know the reason you use NSString! and not String! ?

Comment: I think it is because you never have to test if a constant is nil before using it, so it is "safe" to unwrap it when used. However I would have let NSString but I am not that confortable with swift at this time :)

Comment: I suppose `#define`s and `const`s become constants: i.e. `let`s

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: How does one pass in constants via -DCONSTANT=val on the command line or xcode plist build settings if we change them to let declarations. It kinda misses the whole point of them really.

Answer (score 22):

Just a quick clarification on a few things from above.

Swift Constant are expressed using the keyword`let`

For Example:

```
let kStringConstant:String = "a_string_constant"
```

Also, only in a protocol definition can you use `{ get }`, example:

```
protocol MyExampleProtocol {
    var B:String { get }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In swift you can declare an enum, variable or function outside of any class or function and it will be available in all your classes (globally)(without the need to import a specific file).

```
  import Foundation
  import MapKit

 let kStringConstant:String = "monitoredRegions"

  class UserLocationData : NSObject {    
class func getAllMonitoredRegions()->[String]{
     defaults.dictionaryForKey(kStringConstant)
 }
```

Comment: Do you think it is necessary to declear the type of `kStringConstant` which can be inferred by the content provided, `"monitoredRegins"`.

Comment: Nope not really. Its just a coding practice , any hardcoded string I like to put it on top. Later easily move it out to a constants file.

Answer (score 0):

simple swift language don't need an macros 
all #define directives.
will be let 
and complex macros should convert to be func

Comment: Yes you are correct, [Using Imported C Macros in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_macros_in_swift)

Answer (score -1):

The alternative for macro can be global variable . We can declare global variable outside the class and access those without using class. Please find example below

```
import Foundation
let BASE_URL = "www.google.com"

class test {

}
```