# C array memory deallocation from swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift, interop, xcode6

```
var cpuInfo: processor_info_array_t = nil
var numCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
var coresTotalUsage: Float = 0.0
var numCPUsU: natural_t = 0
let err = host_processor_info(mach_host_self(), PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &numCPUsU, &cpuInfo, &numCpuInfo);
assert(err == KERN_SUCCESS, "Failed call to host_processor_info")
```

Hi, I am calling the above C API `host_processor_info` to get process load informations from swift, no problem there.
`cpuInfo` is a inout parameter (pointer) that, on return, will point to a structure containing the CPU information allocated by that API.
The caller is reponsible for deallocating the memory; I can do that easily from objective C but haven't had any luck in swift. I know I could wrap that call into an objective C extension but I'm trying to learn swift and would like, if possible, avoid the obj-c solution.

in obj-c I would deallocate with:

```
size_t cpuInfoSize = sizeof(integer_t) * numCpuInfo;
vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t) cpuInfo, cpuInfoSize)
```

cpuInfo in swift is an UnsafeMutablePointer not convertible into a vm_address_t.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`processor_info_array_t` is a pointer type, and `vm_address_t` is an integer type
(ultimately an alias for `UInt`). (Judging from the comments in `<i386/vm_types.h>`
this might to be for historical reasons.)
The only way to convert a pointer to an integer (of the same size) in Swift is `unsafeBitCast`.

`mach_init.h` defines

```
extern mach_port_t      mach_task_self_;
#define mach_task_self() mach_task_self_
```

Only the extern variable is visible in Swift, not the macro.

This gives:

```
let cpuInfoSize = vm_size_t(sizeof(integer_t)) * vm_size_t(numCpuInfo)
vm_deallocate(mach_task_self_, unsafeBitCast(cpuInfo, vm_address_t.self), cpuInfoSize)
```

Comment: `var prevCpuInfoSize: vm_size_t = UInt(UInt32(sizeof(integer_t)) * numPrevCpuInfo) as vm_size_t
                vm_deallocate(mach_task_self_, unsafeBitCast(prevCpuInfo, vm_address_t.self), prevCpuInfoSize)`

Thank you Martin! Small modification but that pretty much works, no more memory leaks.

I didn't quite get why just the extern variable is visible in swift and not the macro.

Comment: @Pippo: Some (Objective-)C macros are imported and some are not, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift.

Comment: @Pippo: You are right, I forgot about the multiplication. I have updated the answer as a reference for future readers.

Comment: This still works in Swift 3.1. Just wanna say a thank you, Martin!

Comment: @lightpen: Good to know, thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4, the equivalent code appears to be:

```
let cpuInfoSize = vm_size_t(MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride * Int(numCpuInfo))
vm_deallocate(mach_task_self_, vm_address_t(bitPattern: cpuInfo), cpuInfoSize)
```

In particular, the initializer `UInt(bitPattern:)` is now apparently preferred to `unsafeBitCast()` to initialize an unsigned integer with the bit pattern of a pointer (I guess this usage is not longer considered "unsafe"). It correctly handles a `nil` pointer, returning 0 in this case.