# Swift script to retrieve CPU utilization percentage works fine if run in a loop via Timer. Seems to get stuck on initial percentage without Timer

Tags: swift, macos

I am not a swift developer. I need this swift code to get the current CPU utilization percentage on demand i.e. whenever I query it, I should get the current reading. I need to run this script from a node.js process. It's basically like running the script from Terminal. Here's the script I found from another SO thread that seems to work as it is.

```swift
import Foundation

// CPU usage credit VenoMKO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795612/1033581
class MyCpuUsage {
    var cpuInfo: processor_info_array_t!
    var prevCpuInfo: processor_info_array_t?
    var numCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
    var numPrevCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
    var numCPUs: uint = 0
    var updateTimer: Timer!
    let CPUUsageLock: NSLock = NSLock()

    init() {
        let mibKeys: [Int32] = [ CTL_HW, HW_NCPU ]
        // sysctl Swift usage credit Matt Gallagher: https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlUtils/blob/master/Sources/CwlUtils/CwlSysctl.swift
        mibKeys.withUnsafeBufferPointer() { mib in
            var sizeOfNumCPUs: size_t = MemoryLayout<uint>.size
            let status = sysctl(processor_info_array_t(mutating: mib.baseAddress), 2, &numCPUs, &sizeOfNumCPUs, nil, 0)
            if status != 0 {
                numCPUs = 1
            }
            updateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(updateInfo), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func updateInfo(_ timer: Timer) {
        var totalInUse: Int32 = 0
        var totalTotal: Int32 = 0
        var numCPUsU: natural_t = 0
        let err: kern_return_t = host_processor_info(mach_host_self(), PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &numCPUsU, &cpuInfo, &numCpuInfo);
        
        if err == KERN_SUCCESS {
            CPUUsageLock.lock()

            for i in 0 ..< Int32(numCPUs) {
                var inUse: Int32
                var total: Int32
                if let prevCpuInfo = prevCpuInfo {
                    inUse = cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                        - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                        + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                        - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                        + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                        - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                    total = inUse + (cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)]
                        - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)])
                } else {
                    inUse = cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                        + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                        + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                    total = inUse + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)]
                }

                totalInUse += inUse
                totalTotal += total
            }
            CPUUsageLock.unlock()

            if let prevCpuInfo = prevCpuInfo {
                // vm_deallocate Swift usage credit rsfinn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48630296/1033581
                let prevCpuInfoSize: size_t = MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride * Int(numPrevCpuInfo)
                vm_deallocate(mach_task_self_, vm_address_t(bitPattern: prevCpuInfo), vm_size_t(prevCpuInfoSize))
            }

            prevCpuInfo = cpuInfo
            numPrevCpuInfo = numCpuInfo

            cpuInfo = nil
            numCpuInfo = 0

            let totalUsagePercentage = Float(totalInUse) / Float(totalTotal) * 100
            print(String(format: "Total CPU Usage: %.2f%%", totalUsagePercentage))
        } else {
            print("Error!")
        }
    }
}

let cpuMonitor = MyCpuUsage()
RunLoop.current.run()
```

As you can see this script uses **Timer** and runs indefinitely printing current percentage every 3 seconds on the console. Since I want to print the result only once on demand, here are the modifications I made. Just removed the timer, or I think I did.

```swift
import Foundation

class MyCpuUsage {
    var cpuInfo: processor_info_array_t!
    var prevCpuInfo: processor_info_array_t?
    var numCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
    var numPrevCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
    var numCPUs: uint = 0
    let CPUUsageLock: NSLock = NSLock()

    init() {
        let mibKeys: [Int32] = [ CTL_HW, HW_NCPU ]
        mibKeys.withUnsafeBufferPointer() { mib in
            var sizeOfNumCPUs: size_t = MemoryLayout<uint>.size
            let status = sysctl(processor_info_array_t(mutating: mib.baseAddress), 2, &numCPUs, &sizeOfNumCPUs, nil, 0)
            if status != 0 {
                numCPUs = 1
            }

            // Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(updateInfo), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            // calling the updateInfo() func to print one time result
            updateInfo()
        }
    }

    // Removed exposure to objective-c and the unused parameter "timer"
    // @objc func updateInfo(_ timer: Timer) {
    func updateInfo() {
        // I have added these two variables to calculate sum of all cores
        var totalInUse: Int32 = 0
        var totalTotal: Int32 = 0

        var numCPUsU: natural_t = 0
        let err: kern_return_t = host_processor_info(mach_host_self(), PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &numCPUsU, &cpuInfo, &numCpuInfo);
        if err == KERN_SUCCESS {
            CPUUsageLock.lock()

            for i in 0 ..< Int32(numCPUs) {
                var inUse: Int32
                var total: Int32
                if let prevCpuInfo = prevCpuInfo {
                    inUse = cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                        - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                        + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                        - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                        + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                        - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                    total = inUse + (cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)]
                        - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)])
                } else {
                    inUse = cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                        + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                        + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                    total = inUse + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)]
                }

                // print(String(format: "Core: %u Usage: %f", i, Float(inUse) / Float(total)))
                // Assigning totals here
                totalInUse += inUse
                totalTotal += total
            }
            CPUUsageLock.unlock()

            if let prevCpuInfo = prevCpuInfo {
                let prevCpuInfoSize: size_t = MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride * Int(numPrevCpuInfo)
                vm_deallocate(mach_task_self_, vm_address_t(bitPattern: prevCpuInfo), vm_size_t(prevCpuInfoSize))
            }

            prevCpuInfo = cpuInfo
            numPrevCpuInfo = numCpuInfo

            cpuInfo = nil
            numCpuInfo = 0

            let totalUsagePercentage = Float(totalInUse) / Float(totalTotal) * 100

            // This is where I print sum of all cores percentage.
            print(String(format: "Total CPU Usage: %.2f%%", totalUsagePercentage))
        } else {
            print("Error!")
        }
    }
}

let cpuMonitor = MyCpuUsage()
```

The problem with my modified version is that it seems to print the same percentage on each invocation that it does on the first invocation from the Terminal. Not only the printed value on the console remains the same, but I have also tried running processes to increase CPU usage confirmed by Activity Monitor but this script continues to display the same value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are screenshots from the terminal.

[image: correct values are displayed when running on Timer]

[image: prints 2.45% on each invocation when running the script on-demand]

Comment: In a [comment from VenoMKO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/-/53901721#comment22224805_6795612) on their original answer, they say "_To get the ticks of a period between current moment and a previous call._". Meaning that their code logic is only meaningful when calculated between two calls of `updateInfo()`.
Since your simplification only keeps the first call, you can't calculate the difference with another call, and consequently you can't get the maths correctly.
Fix idea:
Call `updateInfo()` twice, maybe 1 sec wait in-between, and only print the second time.

Comment: @Cœur Thank you for the prompt response. Makes perfect sense. Since I don't speak Swift at all, could you please post a quick modification as an answer? I will also be able to mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula from original code ([in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795612/1033581)) relies on the usage **difference** between two calls to `host_processor_info`. So for your idea to work without a timer, you still need at least two calls to `updateInfo()`. As an example, you can try to `sleep(1)` second in-between.

Code commented.
Tested in Swift Playground.

```
import Foundation

class MyCpuUsage {
    var cpuInfo: processor_info_array_t!
    var prevCpuInfo: processor_info_array_t?
    var numCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
    var numPrevCpuInfo: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
    let numCPUs: uint
    let CPUUsageLock = NSLock()

    init() {
        // obtaining numCPUs
        let mibKeys: [Int32] = [ CTL_HW, HW_NCPU ]
        var numCPUs: uint = 0
        mibKeys.withUnsafeBufferPointer() { mib in
            var sizeOfNumCPUs = MemoryLayout<uint>.size
            let status = sysctl(processor_info_array_t(mutating: mib.baseAddress), 2, &numCPUs, &sizeOfNumCPUs, nil, 0)
            if status != 0 {
                numCPUs = 1
            }
        }
        self.numCPUs = numCPUs

        // calling the updateInfo() func to initialize prevCpuInfo
        updateInfo()
        // sleep 1 second
        sleep(1)
        // calling the updateInfo() func to print cpu usage during past second
        updateInfo()
    }

    func updateInfo() {
        var numCPUsU: natural_t = 0
        let err: kern_return_t = host_processor_info(mach_host_self(), PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &numCPUsU, &cpuInfo, &numCpuInfo);
        guard err == KERN_SUCCESS else {
            print("Error host_processor_info!")
            return
        }

        // Two variables to calculate sum of all cores
        var totalInUse: Int32 = 0
        var totalTotal: Int32 = 0

        CPUUsageLock.lock()

        for i in 0 ..< Int32(numCPUs) {
            var inUse: Int32
            var total: Int32
            if let prevCpuInfo = prevCpuInfo {
                inUse = cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                    - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                    + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                    - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                    + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                    - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                total = inUse + (cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)]
                    - prevCpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)])
            } else {
                inUse = cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_USER)]
                    + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM)]
                    + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_NICE)]
                total = inUse + cpuInfo[Int(CPU_STATE_MAX * i + CPU_STATE_IDLE)]
            }

            // Assigning totals here
            totalInUse += inUse
            totalTotal += total
        }
        CPUUsageLock.unlock()

        if let prevCpuInfo = prevCpuInfo {
            // I free the memory of prevCpuInfo
            let prevCpuInfoSize: size_t = MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride * Int(numPrevCpuInfo)
            vm_deallocate(mach_task_self_, vm_address_t(bitPattern: prevCpuInfo), vm_size_t(prevCpuInfoSize))
            
            // I print sum of all cores percentage.
            let totalUsagePercentage = Float(totalInUse) / Float(totalTotal) * 100
            print(String(format: "Total CPU Usage: %.2f%%", totalUsagePercentage))
        }

        prevCpuInfo = cpuInfo
        numPrevCpuInfo = numCpuInfo

        cpuInfo = nil
        numCpuInfo = 0
    }
}

let cpuMonitor = MyCpuUsage()
```

For the record, that idea of waiting 1 second between the two calls was also documented in 2013 by Anya in a [similar ObjC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20476923/1033581):

> Then we take two samples (1 second between samples)
>
> ```
> sample(&sample1);
> sleep(1);
> sample(&sample2);
> ```

Comment: Thanks a ton :-) This worked perfectly. Somewhere, I also found this method `let hostInfo = host_cpu_load_info_t.allocate(capacity: 1) let _ = hostInfo.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: Int(size)) { (pointer) -> kern_return_t in return host_statistics(mach_host_self(), HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO, pointer, &size) }`  used instead of the simple `host_processor_info` we have in this one. I found both displays pretty much the exact result. Are there any major considerations? differences?

Comment: @zia-khan Neither is properly documented: [`host_statistics`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1502546-host_statistics), [`host_processor_info`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1502854-host_processor_info). So I don't know. Try to read VenoMKO recommendation, maybe the answer is in there: https://github.com/gopalkrishnareddy/awesome-iOS-resource/blob/master/Books/Mac%20Os%20X%20Internals%20-%20A%20Systems%20Approach.pdf

Comment: @zia-khan You may also try to look at the old source code of those methods, which Apple open-sourced some years ago, and that may help you understand the difference between the two API: https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/main/osfmk/kern/host.c

Comment: @zia-khan I read that Anya, in 2013, wrote: ["_But to be honest, I'd use `host_statistics`, as the code is cleaner_"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20476923/1033581)