# Need help converting the following constants.h file to Swift

Tags: swift

I am responsible for converting an iOS application written in Objective C to Swift. One file is the Constant.h has the following code written in it...

```
#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

I cannot import this file in the Objective-C bridging header.What is the Swift equivalent? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create your custom function or computed property to get `IS_IPHONE` and `SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH`. For how to create `#define` in swift, you can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift

Comment: It may be more interesting to convert theses tests which are not recommended to Autolayout/SizeClass stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to figure out what device you are using, I think I would go about it this way:

```
import UIKit

public extension UIDevice {

var modelName: String {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
    let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
        return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }

    switch identifier {
    case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
    case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
    case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
    case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
    case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
    case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
    case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
    case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
    case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
    case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
    case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
    case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
    case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
    case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
    case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
    case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
    case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
    case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
    case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
    case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                      return "iPad Pro"
    case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
    case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
    default:                                        return identifier
    }
}

}
```

You call it like this:

```
let modelName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName
```

Comment: Thank you for citing it. I had it in my code a while back and simply copy pasted from there.