# Swift 2 - Convert objective-c #define to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift2, cgimage

I am trying to convert a [project](https://www.raywenderlich.com/69855/image-processing-in-ios-part-1-raw-bitmap-modification) from objective-c to swift. I have some problems converting #define over swift.

what I have is:

```
    #define Mask8(x) ( (x) & 0xFF )
    #define R(x) ( Mask8(x) )
    #define G(x) ( Mask8(x >> 8 ) )
    #define B(x) ( Mask8(x >> 16) )

UInt32 color = *currentPixel;
      printf("%3.0f ", (R(color)+G(color)+B(color))/3.0);
```

How can I convert this to variable in swift?

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift

Comment: Hi thanks I have seen that tread but I cannot understand why this objective-c macro as `Mark8` and how to convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 `#define`s in your question are not made available to Swift, see the section titled Complex Macros at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

If you want to have their equivalents available in Swift, you will need to re-implement them in Swift.  A simple approach, assuming the macro parameter is of type `UInt32` as it is in your example, might be as follows:

```
func swiftMask8(x:UInt32) -> UInt32
{
    return x & 0xFF
}

func swiftR(x:UInt32)->UInt32
{
    return swiftMask8(x)
}
...
```

Of course, you can drop the `swift` part and just call the functions `Mask8`, 'R`, etc., since their Objective-C equivalents are not visible to Swift anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much ..  At the end I used the function using objective c bridge file ... I will try again to convert it and let you know