# Access #Define macros defined in objective c file from my swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a #define macros define in objective c files which i would like to access in my swift class, I have added the .h file import statements in my bridging header, but for some reason my swift class is not able to recognize my #define constants , Can anyone please suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: `#define` is simply not available in swift, there are no macros. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24326206/2442804

Comment: #define is in my objective c file, I want to access those in swift , is there a way to do it , or do i have to write a complete new code for it to work ?

Comment: probably the later one.

Comment: so how do i access them in swift ?

Comment: "the later one" meaning you have to write new code. Just create a global function or constant

Comment: my app actually is a mixture of objc and swift code and there are many files in objc which uses #define, converting all of them newly is that the best approach ?

Comment: Swift imports some "simple" macros as Swift constants. `#define CONST_A 1` can be imported, but `#define CONST_B (1+2)` cannot be. How's your macros?

Comment: my macro in objc is #define IS_IPHONE_5S() (IS_IPHONE() && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)

Comment: those are bad macros to use anyway. Adopt autolayout. Do not write code that depends on device detection.