# Objective-C macros from prefix project file header is not compiled when Swift file included in framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

[image]

[image]

[image]

If remove swift file from project it is complied successfully. if add then get error.

Comment: Can you share a link to the project to have a look on it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2blcQ9XdtsdVzhvMlZCMERKcTA
archive with test framework project. Just download and build.

Answer (score 0):

`#define`s get converted to Swift by trying to figure out the type. For instance

```
#define B @"b"
```

...becomes:

```
var B: String { get }
```

Find details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326206/1457385).

As your define `#define MY_EXPORT` does not provide a type, the conversion fails.

This code would work:

Prefix.pch:

```
#define MY_EXPORT @"Olala"
```

MyOneClass.m:

```
#import "MyOneClass.h"

@implementation MyOneClass

- (void)method {
    NSString *useIt = MY_EXPORT;
}

@end
```

Comment: The thing is that use this macros as I described in header file?!?!
For .m file, you are right, it works.

Comment: Please show an example of the problem, using a proper type.