# Swift 4 Conditional compile logic not working correctly

Tags: compilation, syntax-error, conditional-statements, swift4

Here's some simple code to show the problem I am having:

```
import UIKit

let TEST = true
print(TEST)
#if TEST
    print("1. TEST should be true. Value is : ", TEST)
#endif

#if !TEST
    print("2. TEST should be false.  Value is : ", TEST)
#endif
```

Regardless of whether TEST is 'true' or 'false', the '#if !TEST' is always executed. The '#if TEST' branch is never executed.

This happens in a Playground and in compiled code.
Xcode 9 Beta 5

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift

Comment: var TEST = true

Comment: I changed 'let TEST = true' to 'var TEST = true', but I still get the same erroneous behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing between `TEST` the local variable and `TEST` the compiler flag.

- What you have is a local variable named `TEST`
- What you are testing for is the existence of a compiler flag named `TEST`

To set a compiler flag, go to the target's Build Settings and search for `Other Swift Flags`, then add `-DTEST` to your Debug build.

Also, Swift compiler flags are much simpler compared to C compiler flags: a flag either exists or not. You can't associate an int value or anything like that. Consequently, there's no point in getting its value. It's a true/false situation: you know that it exists or not; there's no other value associated with it.

Comment: CD, thanks for your response I had suspected something like that, but i couldn't find any good description. If I want more than one flag, do they go on the same line?