# use #define in objective C and access in swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have define `#define baseUrl [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api/v4", MAINURL]` in objective c class and can access anywhere in project. But now i have created swift file in exiting objective c project and want to  access baseurl in swift but error received.

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'baseUrl'
```

how can resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a Objective-C #define from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Importing Objective-C macros into Swift doesn't always work. According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective_c_apis/using_imported_c_macros_in_swift):

> Swift automatically imports simple, constant-like macros, declared with the #define directive, as global constants. Macros are imported when they use literals for string, floating-point, or integer values, or use operators like +, -, >, and == between literals or previously defined macros.
>
> **C macros that are more complex than simple constant definitions have no counterpart in Swift.**

An alternative in your case would be to use a function that returns the value defined by macro

```
// .h file
#define baseUrl [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api/v4", MAINURL]
+ (NSString*) BaseUrl;

// .m file
+ (NSString*) BaseUrl { return baseUrl }
```

Comment: How can we manage same #define constant for different schemes ? If we have different targets we are able to add #ifdef (Target_Name) #endif. But if we have only have 1 target and multiple schemes then how to use #if condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Objective-C `#define` could not access by swift.

Maybe you change your `#defines` to actual constants, which is better than `#defines`.

Or create a swift object hold some static variable.

For example:

```
class API: NSObject {
    static let apiPrefix = "https://vvv"
    static let apiPosts = apiPrefix + "posts"
}
```

Calling: `API.apiPosts`

Comment: i am using now extern NSString* const baseUrlV4 @"abc" but can't access

Comment: how can use actual constants?

Comment: try to defined `extern NSString* const baseUrlV4` and put that .h file into Bridging-Header.h