# iOS: How to get the #define from a Constant.h ObjC in a Swift File?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, constants, string-concatenation

When I write this in the constant.h file:

```
#define WS_PLANNING_INFORMATION "registrations/"
```

It works when I call it from the Swift file.

But if I write this in the constant.h file:

```
#define WS_PLANNING_INFORMATION "registrations/" CRYPTOKEY
```

It doesn't work. The swift file doesn't see the WS_PLANNING_INFORMATION anymore.

Is there an easy way to concatenate two strings in the constant.h file to be well-retrieved by the swift file?

(The validate answer to this question is very useful and more simple than in that [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170953/use-define-in-objective-c-and-access-in-swift-class), that doesn't suit me)

Comment: Nope. You should not have used macros for string constants in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use constants instead of macros.

in constant.h

```
extern const char *WS_PLANNING_INFORMATION;
```

in constant.m

```
const char *WS_PLANNING_INFORMATION = "registrations/" CRYPTOKEY;
```

---

If you mean to use `NSString *` instead of `char *`

in constant.h

```
extern const NSString *WS_PLANNING_INFORMATION;
```

in constant.m

```
const NSString *WS_PLANNING_INFORMATION = @"registrations/" CRYPTOKEY;
```

Comment: There so many time that I am looking for that. Thank you very much :D